# ionic cordova run browser errors

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

I am trying to run a live reload in the browser as i need to be able to see the camera working but i'm just running into one issue after another.

> Command: ionic cordova run browser --livereload

The current error is this:

> [ng] An unhandled exception occurred: Job name "..getProjectMetadata"
> does not exist.

These errors don't even state where it's coming from, but here is my package... it seems to be related to the build-angular package but no matter what i do it either has the error above or the following depending on what version is used:

> Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path ""
> should NOT have additional properties(project)

```
{
  "name": "org.apache.cordova.newapp",
  "displayName": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.10",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/media-capture": "^5.37.3",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^5.0.3",
    "@ionic/core": "^5.8.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.28.28",
    "angular-flatpickr": "^3.6.6",
    "angular-linky": "^1.2.2",
    "angular-password-strength-meter": "^3.0.1",
    "angularx-flatpickr": "^6.6.0",
    "angularx-social-login": "^3.5.7",
    "date-fns": "^2.25.0",
    "emoji-js": "^3.6.0",
    "flatpickr": "^4.6.9",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^7.0.2",
    "ng-socket-io": "^0.2.4",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
    "ngb-modal": "^2.0.3",
    "ngx-emoji-picker": "0.0.2",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^10.1.1",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^3.3.5",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^9.1.0",
    "ngx-lightbox": "^2.5.1",
    "ngx-paypal": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.3.3",
    "ngx-ui-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.14.1",
    "ws": "^7.5.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1",
    "zxcvbn3": "^0.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.29",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^9.1.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ecosystem:cordova"
  ],
  "author": "Apache Cordova Team",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-media-capture": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "browser"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: the entire app? that's not possible, this happens when i try to build it

Comment: use ionic serve

Comment: @RaviAshara i need cordova camera to work so i'm serving in browser mode